# Bring main window to top on PySide

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

**The scenario:**

So basically what I have is 3 different windows and 1 windows manager file. The windows manager starts one of the windows (main one) and from ther you can open the other windows. So far so good. However, the new windows are **always on top** of the main window.
We can check that if we open all windows and we click on `test1` or `test2` the "always on top" focus switches and we get on top the one where we clicked, so we can easily read the text on each of them.

**The issue:**

This behavior doesn't happens with the `main` window. No matter what, the main window is always in the back and if the other windows are opened you can't bring the `main` window it to the front.

I want to bring it to the front, so I've been trying different approachs. The commented function on windows manager is a list of some of the things that I tried.

**Notes:**

I am using  Python 3.7, PySide2 and Qt5.11 on Windows 10.

If I recall correctly, this also happens on PyQt5.

This is just the smallest example, on my production code we have 40 windows that are 600% bigger than the main menu, and if we want to open a new window from it we have to move our current window away to "find" where is the menu.

I have been reading this sort of limitation might be from windows itself, but then, if there is nothing to do I need advice at this point.

- How can I create a multi-windows based application where my opened windows doesn't hide the main menu?

I am a self-taught programmaer and this is the first time that I code a windows manager for a GUI, so feel free to suggest a different way to how to build a windows manager.

```
#####################
# main_ui.py file
#####################

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(997, 554)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 997, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuWindows = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuWindows.setObjectName("menuWindows")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setBold(False)
        self.statusbar.setFont(font)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionTest2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionTest2.setObjectName("actionTest2")
        self.actionTest1 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionTest1.setObjectName("actionTest1")
        self.menuWindows.addAction(self.actionTest1)
        self.menuWindows.addSeparator()
        self.menuWindows.addAction(self.actionTest2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuWindows.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Multiwindows tests", None, -1))
        self.menuWindows.setTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Windows", None, -1))
        self.actionTest2.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Test2", None, -1))
        self.actionTest1.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Test1", None, -1))






#####################
# main_logic.py file
#####################

from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import QPoint, QSize, QEvent, Qt
from main_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class MenuForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    """Main window of the program."""

    def __init__(self, windows_manager, parent=None):
        """Set the initial state of the window"""
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # Initial window size/pos.
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(400, 300))
        self.resize(self.maximumSize())
        self.move(QPoint(300, 300))
        # Pointer to windows manager
        self.WINDOWS_HANDLER = windows_manager
        # Buttons: QMenubar/Windows
        self.actionTest1.triggered.connect(self.WINDOWS_HANDLER.open_window_test1)
        self.actionTest2.triggered.connect(self.WINDOWS_HANDLER.open_window_test2)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """Say to the windows handler that we closed this window"""
        self.WINDOWS_HANDLER.window_is_closed(self)
        event.accept()
        # Special: Force a close of the whole program if other windows are opened
        self.WINDOWS_HANDLER.kill_program()





#####################
# test1_ui.py file
#####################

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Test1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Test1):
        Test1.setObjectName("Test1")
        Test1.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        Test1.resize(450, 259)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Test1)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.labelNota = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labelNota.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 50, 231, 111))
        self.labelNota.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(100, 100, 100);")
        self.labelNota.setWordWrap(True)
        self.labelNota.setObjectName("labelNota")
        Test1.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Test1)
        self.statusbar.setStyleSheet("")
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Test1.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Test1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Test1)

    def retranslateUi(self, Test1):
        Test1.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Test1", "Test1 window", None, -1))
        self.labelNota.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Test1", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" font-weight:600;\">This is the test1 window.</span></p></body></html>", None, -1))





#####################
# test1_logic.py file
#####################

from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import QPoint, QSize
from test1_ui import Ui_Test1

class Test1Form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Test1):
    """Main window of the program."""

    def __init__(self, windows_manager, parent=None):
        """Set the initial state of the window"""
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # Initial window size/pos
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(300, 300))
        self.resize(self.maximumSize())
        self.move(QPoint(400, 100))
        # Pointer to windows manager
        self.WINDOWS_HANDLER = windows_manager

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """Say to the windows handler that we closed this window"""
        self.WINDOWS_HANDLER.window_is_closed(self)
        event.accept()





#####################
# test2_ui.py file
#####################

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Test2(object):
    def setupUi(self, Test2):
        Test2.setObjectName("Test2")
        Test2.resize(1312, 1005)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Test2)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.labelNota = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labelNota.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 201, 101))
        self.labelNota.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(100, 100, 100);")
        self.labelNota.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.labelNota.setWordWrap(True)
        self.labelNota.setObjectName("labelNota")
        Test2.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Test2)
        self.statusbar.setStyleSheet("")
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Test2.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Test2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Test2)

    def retranslateUi(self, Test2):
        Test2.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Test2", "Test2 window", None, -1))
        self.labelNota.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Test2", "<html><head/><body><p>This is the test2 window</p></body></html>", None, -1))





#####################
# test1_logic.py file
#####################

from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import QPoint, QSize
from test2_ui import Ui_Test2

class Test2Form(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Test2):
    """Main window of the program."""

    def __init__(self, windows_manager, parent=None):
        """Set the initial state of the window"""
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # Initial window size/pos
        self.setMaximumSize(QSize(300, 300))
        self.resize(self.maximumSize())
        self.move(QPoint(450, 100))
        # Pointer to windows manager
        self.WINDOWS_HANDLER = windows_manager

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """Say to the windows handler that we closed this window"""
        self.WINDOWS_HANDLER.window_is_closed(self)
        event.accept()










##########################
# windows_manager.py file
##########################

from main_logic import  MenuForm
from test1_logic import Test1Form
from test2_logic import Test2Form
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt


class WindowsHandler(object):
    """Main handler of the windows system"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Set the initial instances of the windows"""
        self.active_windows = []
        # Set first window - Menu one
        self.menu_instance = MenuForm(self)
        self.active_windows.append(self.menu_instance)
        self.menu_instance.show()

    def window_is_closed(self, window):
        """Choose what to do when a window is closed"""
        if window in self.active_windows:
            self.active_windows.remove(window)

    def handle_windows(self, window_base, app=None):
        """Check if we should add or remove an item, also log it"""
        for window in self.active_windows:
            if isinstance(window, window_base):
                self.menu_instance.statusbar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(200, 0, 0);color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
                self.menu_instance.statusbar.showMessage("That window is already opened")
                break
        else:
            if app is None:
                window_instance = window_base(self, self.menu_instance)
            else:
                window_instance = window_base(self, self.menu_instance, app)
            self.active_windows.append(window_instance)
            self.menu_instance.statusbar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 200, 0);color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
            self.menu_instance.statusbar.showMessage("A new window has been opened")
            return window_instance
        return None

    # def set_window_top(self, top_window):
    #     """Set the window as top window"""
    #     print("first attempt")
    #     top_window.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMinimized | Qt.WindowActive)
    #     top_window.raise_()
    #     top_window.activateWindow()
    #     top_window.showNormal()
    #     print("second attempt")
    #     top_window.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    #     APPLICATION.setActiveWindow(top_window)
    #     top_window.raise_()

    def open_window_test1(self):
        """Open the assigned window and add a pointer"""
        instance = self.handle_windows(Test1Form)
        if instance is not None:
            instance.show()

    def open_window_test2(self):
        """Open the assigned window and add a pointer"""
        instance = self.handle_windows(Test2Form)
        if instance is not None:
            instance.show()

    @staticmethod
    def kill_program():
        """Close all windows to trigger an exit of the program"""
        APPLICATION.closeAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    # App
    APPLICATION = QApplication(sys.argv)
    APPLICATION.setAttribute(Qt.AA_DisableWindowContextHelpButton)
    # Project data
    WINDOWS_HANDLER = WindowsHandler()
    sys.exit(APPLICATION.exec_())
```

**Questions:**

Why `_raise()` doesn't works on this window?
What does it works to get the same results?

Comment: In SO a question must be asked by POST, for that reason the button says **Ask Question**, you do not say **Ask Questions**.

Comment: Creating 3 posts for the same exact issue, but with 3 different questions would be highly inefficient.

Comment: On the other hand, it uses the appropriate tag, PySide2 is not PyQt5, PySide2 currently has many bugs that do not appear in PyQt5 and vice versa, etc.

Comment: The same thing happens on PyQt5 when I tried, so it's unlikely to be a bug of just PySide2

Comment: and if the solution only works for PyQt5 and not for PySide2 or vice versa, it has happened to me many times, it is best to use the correct tag.

Comment: @Saelyth. Try creating the test windows without a parent. FWIW, `raise_()` works fine for me on linux, with or without a parent. To also activate the main window after showing a test window, I had to use a single-shot timer, because things work asynchronously on X11. However, I don't think that would be needed on windows.

Comment: My god, it works @ekhumoro. If you could you explain why it works that way on an answer I'd accept that as valid.

Comment: @Saelyth. I can't do any testing on windows to see what the exact behaviour is. What happens if you set a parent on the test windows, but add the `Qt.Window` flag to them instead? (That is: `testwin.setWindowFlags(testwin.windowFlags() | Qt.Window)`). Does that fix the original problem as well?

Comment: Nope, that was something that I tried. I tried all the different windowFlag combinations with no luck before I asked in SO, the main window was always in the back. It make sense that it was because It's the parent after all. After your comment I actually tried again but yet it won't work. Only removing the parent from `QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)` fixes this behavior. That's the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the test window without a parent fixed this question.

```
QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
```